# Is there an existing parser for iCalendar files for PHP?

Tags: php, icalendar

I've been searching for an iCalendar parser for PHP, but have been unable to find a complete one. [qCal](http://www.ohloh.net/p/qcal) doesn't seem complete. [Bennu](http://bennu.sourceforge.net/) seems even less so. I've seen a lot of people wanting one, but not much else.

Answer (score 7):

sabre-vobject is another (disclaimer: mine). It's been tested in a lot of environments, and provides a natural 'SimpleXML'-like interface to iCalendars and vCards.

http://sabre.io/vobject/

Answer (score 6):

After an endless search I finally found a good one, with great documentation:

http://www.kigkonsult.se/iCalcreator/

Answer (score 5):

You may also check out [SG iCalendar](https://github.com/fangel/SG-iCalendar). It's very simple to use and seems to be well commented.

Comment: After trying them all, this one took about a minute to get working. Sabre is very detailed, but didn't like the .ics file I had (even using the compatible mode). Thanks m-s!

Answer (score 0):

There are others ..

- http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpicalendar/
- http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/9224
- http://php-ical.nuclearscripts.com/

Comment: Those are all the same project. I looked through it before and it seems very closely tied with its own display mechanism.