# How to put specific strings in array with specific keys PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have a string pulling from a socket: (it is a single string with no escapes (/r/n))

```
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 10.0 MIMEDIR//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-CALENDARSERVER-ACCESS:PUBLIC
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Pacific Time
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:20081101T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=11;BYDAY=1SU
....
```

I would like to have it so it is like this:

```
$data['PRODID'] = -//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 10.0 MIMEDIR//EN
$data['VERSION'] = 2.0
.......
```

I did try parse_str but that didn't work. Is there a easy way?

Comment: The problem you are going to run into is that you have duplicate key values.... BEGIN appears twice.

Comment: Go over the input line by line and split by ":"

Comment: Provided an answer that shows how to deal with the duplicate key's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be pretty trivial to write your own script to interpret this.

```
$lines = explode("\r\n", $string);
$parsed = array();
foreach($lines as $line){
    list($key, $value) = explode(":", $line, 2);
    $parsed[$key] = $value;
}
```

Immediately I see one point where your script will stop making sense though and that is the duplicate begin key.

To deal with this  you can do something along these lines:

```
$lines = explode("\n", $string);
$parsed = array();
$current = &$parsed;
foreach($lines as $line){
    list($key, $value) = explode(":", $line, 2);
    if ($key == "BEGIN") {
         $parsed[$value] = array();
         $current = &$parsed[$value];
    } else {
         $current[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

This will yield output like

```
Array
(
    [PRODID] => -//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 10.0 MIMEDIR//EN
    [VERSION] => 2.0
    [METHOD] => PUBLISH
    [X-CALENDARSERVER-ACCESS] => PUBLIC
    [VTIMEZONE] => Array
        (
            [TZID] => Pacific Time
        )

    [STANDARD] => Array
        (
            [DTSTART] => 20081101T020000
            [RRULE] => FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=11;BYDAY=1SU
        )

)
```

For the above example (note how everything after a begin block is set as a property to a subarray based on the BEGIN's value).

[See it in Action](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/bau-mdr)

For an Alternative implementation of a iCalendar Parser you can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096007/is-there-an-existing-parser-for-icalendar-files-for-php)

Comment: Hi, There is no \n (or \r\n), it is a single line retrieved from the socket. I thought I mentioned that, sorry. Your very close. :)

Comment: @user1873432 If you are seeing the display as shown (on separate lines) then there is a newline and possibly a carriage return. If that was not the case then the string is all on one line.

Comment: Based on the [icalendar spec](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2445) The delimiter should be `\r\n`. Updated the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

do it like this?

```
$string = "...." // all the stuff you have there.

$array = array();

// explode on newlines to go through it line by line
foreach(explode("\n", $string) as $line)
{
    // explode again by ':' and set the key/values
    $tmp = explode(':', $line);
    $array[$tmp[0]] = $tmp[1];
}
```

just be aware that you're going to overwrite keys. (you have BEGIN twice).