# How to parse Ical file from Facebook Events in PHP Regex?

Tags: php, regex, icalendar

I am trying to parse the `Summary` and `DTSTART` fields in this data and thought about using regex. Also tried reading line by line but couldn't work around the logic to implement it.

Anyone help out?

There are already made parsers out there but my requirements are abit unique and require a different targeted implementation.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Facebook//NONSGML Facebook Events V1.0//EN
X-WR-CALNAME:Friends' birthdays
X-PUBLISHED-TTL:PT12H
X-ORIGINAL-URL:/events/birthdays/
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20170106
SUMMARY:Gys's birthday
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY
DURATION:P1D
UID:b1074083@facebook.com
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20130406
SUMMARY:Geo's birthday
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY
DURATION:P1D
UID:b1004@facebook.com
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20120602
SUMMARY:Flo's birthday
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY
DURATION:P1D
UID:b100895@facebook.com
END:VEVENT
```

Comment: Please add what you've already tried. Line by line you could explode on `:`. or maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096007/is-there-an-existing-parser-for-icalendar-files-for-php is worth look at

Comment: Project doesn't allow to use existing parsers. Line by line made send but only if  i am processing a section like between `BEGIN:VEVENT` and `END:VEVENT`,  else how would i know who DTSTART belongs to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096007/is-there-an-existing-parser-for-icalendar-files-for-php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an existing parser for iCalendar files for PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096007/is-there-an-existing-parser-for-icalendar-files-for-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code reads all of the file into an array (using `file()`) and then processes each line at a time.  Each line is split into the tag and the content parts and then depending on what tag it is, it will either store the data temporarily or add the accumulated content into the overall calendar array.   ...

```
$file = "a.txt";
$calendar = [];
$lines = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$temp = [];
$type = "";
foreach ( $lines as $line ) {
    list($tag,$content) = explode(":", $line);
    if ( $tag == "END" )    {
        $calendar[$type][] = $temp;
        $temp = [];
    }
    else if ( $tag == "BEGIN" )   {
        // If already some content, then store it in calendar and reset
        if ( count($temp) > 0 ) {
            $calendar[$type][] = $temp;
            $temp = [];
        }
        $type = $content;
    }
    else    {
        $temp[$tag] = $content;
    }
}
```

It uses the BEGIN tag content to store the events of the various parts of the file together, with the sample data file it will give...

```
Array
(
    [VCALENDAR] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [PRODID] => -//Facebook//NONSGML Facebook Events V1.0//EN
                    [X-WR-CALNAME] => Friends' birthdays
                    [X-PUBLISHED-TTL] => PT12H
                    [X-ORIGINAL-URL] => /events/birthdays/
                    [VERSION] => 2.0
                    [CALSCALE] => GREGORIAN
                    [METHOD] => PUBLISH
                )

        )

    [VEVENT] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [DTSTART] => 20170106
                    [SUMMARY] => Gys's birthday
                    [RRULE] => FREQ=YEARLY
                    [DURATION] => P1D
                    [UID] => b1074083@facebook.com
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [DTSTART] => 20130406
                    [SUMMARY] => Geo's birthday
                    [RRULE] => FREQ=YEARLY
                    [DURATION] => P1D
                    [UID] => b1004@facebook.com
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [DTSTART] => 20120602
                    [SUMMARY] => Flo's birthday
                    [RRULE] => FREQ=YEARLY
                    [DURATION] => P1D
                    [UID] => b100895@facebook.com
                )

        )

)
```